# Automate dir and DB stack creation with WP-CLI

Tags: database, installation, wp-cli, automation

This is how I create a database stack and a directory for WordPress in my Ubuntu environment:

```
cat <<-DBSTACK | mysql -u root -p"${dbrootp}"
    CREATE USER "${domain}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${dbuserp}";
    CREATE DATABASE "${domain}";
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO "${domain}"@"localhost";
DBSTACK

curl -L http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz | tar -zx -C ${domain}/
cp ${domain}/wp-config-sample.php ${domain}/wp-config.php
sed -ir "s/username_here|database_name_here/${domain}/g ; s/password_here/${dbuserp}/g" ${domain}"/ ${domain}/wp-config.php
```

How would you reduce the amount of code with WP-CLI to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP-CLI has a bunch of helpful [commands](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/), including some to perform basic [database operations](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/).

However, it's not its job to create new users in MySQL and grant them permissions on a newly created database. So that part of your script can't really be replaced with WP-CLI.

You're still in luck though. The [`wp core`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/) command will help you download, install, update and manage a WordPress install. Plus [`wp config`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/) helps you manage the `wp-config.php` file.

Instead of `curl -L http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz | tar -zx -C ${domain}/` you can simply use `wp core download` to install the latest version of WordPress.

To add the database credentials to the config file, you can use `wp config create --dname="${domain}" --dbuser="${domain}" --dbpass=${dbuserp}`.

But we're not done yet! Why not fully install WordPress while we're at it? This can be done using `wp core install`:

```
wp core install --url=example.com --title=Example --admin_user=supervisor --admin_password=strongpassword --admin_email=info@example.com
```